# For a real matrix A, if $x^{T}Ax > 0$ for all x then is A invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

The original question is

If $A, B$ are real $n \times n$ matrices such that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite and $B$ is such that $B^{T} = -B$, then is $A + B$ invertible ?

##### MY APPROACH

Let $ C = A + B$, then we have $C^{T} = A^{T} + B^{T} = A - B$. So $C$ is not a symmetric matrix. Considering

$$x^{T}Cx = x^{T}Ax + x^{T}Bx = x^{T}Ax > 0$$

for every $x \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$. Note that $x^{T}Bx = 0$ as $B^{T} = -B$. This comes to original question that if $x^{T}Cx > 0$ then will it be invertible ?. If it was symmetric then we will have positive definite matrix which will make it as invertible but this is not the case here.

So we basically have to prove that $C$ doesn't have zero as its eigen value. As its real matrix it can have complex eigen values or real eigen values or mix of them. Here we just have to prove that if real eigen value is present then it can't be zero. If $\lambda$ is real eigen value, then $\lambda x^{T}x > 0$ which says $\lambda > 0$ (because $x$ will be real vector as eigen value is also real, the we can say that $x^{T}x > 0$) which proves that C is invertible.

#### EDIT

In my argument, I am assuming that $x$ is not zero vector. Thanks @hardmath

Is the argument or approach correct or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes. A positive definite matrix cannot have zero as eigenvalue, so the product of determinant cannot be 0.

Comment: The reason I have added the title like that because my original problem got reduced to $x^{T}Cx > 0$ but $C$ is not symmetric. If you think that then also the title is wrong, then I will edit it.

Thanks

Comment: It is necessary  to eliminate $x=0$ in your assumptions since for $x=0$, clearly $x^T C x = 0$ for any matrix $C$ of appropriate dimensions.

Comment: @hardmath,  yeah you are correct. I should have started with the argument that $x$ is not zero vector.

I have edited the question.

Comment: If $C x = 0$ implies $x = 0$, then $C$ is invertible. This is the case here because $Cx = 0$ implies $x^T A x = 0$.

Comment: Prove the contrapositive. Or use proof by contradiction. It's a one-liner.

Comment: Pleas forget about my (now deleted) comment. It was a mistake. + Your argument is correct but could be written more simply, like in Gribouillis' comment.

Comment: The symmetry has nothing to do with the conclusion. If $x^TCx\neq 0$ for all $x\neq 0,$ then $\ker C=\{0\}.$